# Draw a colourful line and end with a dot / circle under the text using css

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

How to draw a colorful line and end with a dot under the text using css like this picture?

The underline start with spaces / padding.

[image: picture]

```css
.underline {
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-underline-offset: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 0px;
  color: #2af6ff;
}

.underline::before {
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: #2af6ff;
  bottom: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  content: '';
  width: 10px;
  left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="h3 fw-bolder mt-4 px-5"><span class="underline">Summary</span></div>
```

Comment: You could try using a the [Pseudo Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) `::after` and positioning it where it relative to the parent container.

Comment: use ::after element with a background gradient and do some position transformation to accomplish this

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working example of what you want

```css
.underline{    
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px 0px;
    color: #2af6ff;  
}
.underline::before {
  position: absolute;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(147,73,209,1) 0%, rgba(83,241,254,1) 100%);
  bottom: 10px;
  height: 4px;
  content: '';
  width: calc(100% - 2px);
  left: 0;
  transform:translateY(-2px);
}

.underline::after {
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: #2af6ff;
  bottom: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  content: '';
  width: 10px;
  left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="h3 fw-bolder mt-4 px-5"><span class="underline">Summary</span></div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
.fw-bolder {
    --start-color: #0099ff;
    --end-color: #2af6ff;
}

.underline {  
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 20px 0px;
    color: #2af6ff;  
    text-align: right;
}

.underline::before {
  content: "";
  height: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 4px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, var(--start-color), var(--end-color) 80%);
}

.underline::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: var(--end-color);
}
```

Pseudo element "before" is used for border bottom (it isn't a real border, so you can use linear gradient as background), and "after" is used for circle at right.

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the use of an HTML element which is merely adding some styling - try to keep content and style separate.

This snippet uses both before and after pseudo elements to create the line and the circle.

A linear-gradient background image is given to the line.

Padding is given to the element itself on the left hand side and box-sizing is set to border-box so that the word is offset but the pseudo element drawing the line can pick up the full width.

```css
.underline {
  padding-left: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #2af6ff
}

.underline::before {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: 0;
  top: calc(100% + 10px);
  z-index: 1;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, purple, #2af6ff);
}

.underline::after {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: #2af6ff;
  top: calc(100% + 10px);
  height: 10px;
  content: '';
  width: 10px;
  left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="underline">Summary</div>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Two gradients can do the job

```css
.underline {
  --s: 12px; /* control the size */

  padding-left: 100px;
  padding-bottom: calc(var(--s) + .3em);
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #2af6ff;
  background: 
    no-repeat linear-gradient(90deg, purple, #2af6ff)
     0 calc(100% - calc(var(--s)/3))/100% calc(var(--s)/3),
    radial-gradient(#2af6ff 70%,#0000 72%)
     100% 100%/var(--s) var(--s) no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="underline">Summary</div>
```